# CSS - drop down menu is missing in Safari

Tags: css, user-interface

Using one of jquery plungin to display as Flyout styles menu.

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/bNj4R/

It's so strange in Safari browser, when you click a top level menu from fifth top, It does not showing any children menus.

I found It's something do with following css in  jqueryUI.css

```
.ui-helper-clearfix:before, .ui-helper-clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

It's all working great in other browsers. expect safari.

Please check http://jsfiddle.net/bNj4R/

---

Fixed , Forced to make a scroll to top. before display sub menus.

$('.fg-menu.fg-menu-scroll').scrollTop('0');

Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like safari isn't scrolling the box to the top again. That's the reason why the first 5 work and the rest don't. Once you scroll, Safari keeps that position when it brings up the submenu.

I think it's possibly a bug with fgMenu library. Looking at the lirbary, it's 5 years old and it's pretty hefty in size. Might be worth having a hunt around for a more current menu library. Can do a bunch of things with css these days.